# Почему get_template_directory_uri() не возвращает полный путь?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/сss/stylr.css
```

Код выше возвращает `http://mydomain/css/style.css`

А должно быть `http://mydomain/wp-content/themes/sky/css/style.css`

Comment: возможно есть фильтр который правит линку, поище функции привязанные к этому фильтру template_directory_uri

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать функцию [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) - она вернет правильный путь в случае работы и в дочерней, и в родительской теме

Функции [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) и  [get_template_directory_uri()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_directory_uri) похожи, но есть некоторые отличия:

- [get_template_directory_uri()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_directory_uri) всегда будет ссылаться на папку
  родительской темы для ресурсов.
- [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) будет ссылаться на «текущую» папку темы
  для ресурсов (которая может быть родительской или дочерней, в
  зависимости от того, где она вызывается).